# Store button cannot install from file

Tags: outlook, manifest, outlook-addin

I have trouble installing a manifest xml in Outlook 2016 as an add-in. 
When I click the Store button in ribbon to install an xml file for an add-in, instead of showing [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jnsW2.png), it redirects to a web url which shows [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZFgU4.png).

Comment: What makes you think that the view from the web interface of the Office store has to match to the view inside Outlook desktop application? Store view inside Outlook will show subset of Office applications from the store related to Outlook only.

Comment: no, its not that it should match. It opens a web url instead of opening just a form inside the outlook desktop app